# Lightning Components | dynamic field Error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, fields, builder

I'm trying to build a dynamic Lightning Component using Design Resources.
The user should choose 1 object and 3 fields and the component will show the records of that object and the 3 fields.
Problem is:
I'm writing my fields with variables but the component give me this error:

> Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details. This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. rerender threw an error in 'markup://aura:iteration' [Assertion Failed!: Unable to get value for key 'art.text__c'. No value provider was found for 'art'. : false] Failing descriptor: {markup://aura:iteration}

The only way to make this component work normally it's to put the fields manually, let's say the user will choose the object "Contact" and the fields Name, Birthdate and email, if i put the fields like this:

{!art.Name}
{!art.Birthdate}
{!art.Email}

It works! But if i put the exact same thing but by variable...here comes the error!
My question is: Why the component is accepting

> {!art.Birthdate}

but it's not acepting the variable that brings the exact same thing ? 
PS: The "{!v.componentname}" it's for user to choose the name of the component, and that it's working fine by variable.

My component:

```
<aura:component controller="ArticlesClass" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="Articles" type="string"/>
<aura:attribute name="componentname" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="object" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="titlename" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="textname" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="imgname" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="title" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="text" type="String"/>   
<aura:attribute name="img" type="String"/> 
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" /> 

<aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.showSpinner}"/>
<aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.hideSpinner}"/>

<div class="lista-artigos" id="lista-artigos">
<div class="panel-header" id="panel-header">
    <h1>{!v.componentname}</h1> 
</div> 
        <ul class="search-artigos">
            <li><input id="search" class="search" type="search" onkeyup="{!c.searchKey}" /></li>
        </ul>
            <div id="feed" class="loop-artigos">
                <!-- Passa o parâmetro para carregar os artigos -->
                <center><ui:spinner aura:id="spinner"/></center>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.Articles}" var="art">
               <div class="artigo">
                    <div class="thumb">
                       {!v.img}
                    </div>
                    <div class="corpo-artigo">
                        <h1 id="titleforarticle">{!v.title}</h1>
                        <p  id="textforarticle">{!v.text}</p>
                    </div>  
                </div> 
                </aura:iteration>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </aura:component>
```

My Controller:

```
     doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
     console.log("doInit");
    helper.Init(component, event);
    },
```

My Design Resource:

```
<design:component label="Article List">
<design:attribute name="componentname" label="Choose the name of the component" description="It will appear in the blue header"/>
<design:attribute name="object" label="Enter the name of the object"/>
<design:attribute name="titlename" label="Enter the name of the title field"/>    
<design:attribute name="textname" label="Enter the name of the text field" description="Should be a summary of the article"/>
<design:attribute name="imgname" label="Enter the name of the image field" />
</design:component>
```

My Apex Class

```
public with sharing class ArticlesClass {
@AuraEnabled
public static list<Sobject> getArticles(string obj, string titlefield, string textfield, string imgfield) {
    try{
        string query = 'SELECT '+titlefield+', '+textfield+', '+imgfield+' FROM '+obj+'';
        list<Sobject> ArticlesReturn = database.query(query);
        return ArticlesReturn;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

My helper:

```
    Init: function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.getArticles");
    var action2 = component.get("c.findArticles");
    action.setParams({
    obj: component.get("v.object"),
    titlefield: component.get("v.titlename"),
    textfield: component.get("v.textname"),
    imgfield: component.get("v.imgname")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
    component.set("v.Articles", a.getReturnValue()); 
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    var b = component.get("v.titlename");
    var c = component.get("v.textname");
    var d = component.get("v.imgname");
    component.set("v.title", "{!art." + b + "}");
    component.set('v.text', "{!art." + c + "}");  
    component.set('v.img', "{!art." + d + "}"); 
}
```